# Passing multidimensional arrays by void functions

Tags: c

This is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int funk1()
{
int N=0;
float a;
FILE *f;
f=fopen("wyniki.txt", "r");
while(fscanf(f,"%f", &a)!=EOF)
{
    N++;
}
fclose(f);
return N;
}

void funk2(int N, float T[][N])
{
FILE *f;
f=fopen("wyniki.txt", "r");
float a;
int i=0;
while(fscanf(f,"%f", &a)!=EOF)
{
    T[i][0]=a;
    T[0][i]=a;

    printf("funk 2\n");
    printf("liczba = %f    i = %d \n", a, i);
    printf("%f   %f\n", T[i][0], T[0][i]);


    i++;
}
fclose(f);

}

main()
{
int N =  funk1();
float T[N][N];

funk2(N,T[][N]);

int i=0;
int j=0;

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        printf("|%f|\t",T[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("|%f|\t", T[i][j]);
}

getch();
return 0;
}
```

The problem is only with funk2. I want to pass the matrix (T) from main to funk2, do stuff with it and then give it back to main. I have no idea how to do that to be honest, I just tried out messing with it but it doesn't work. Any idea how to do that? Should I provide more information or is this enough? You can ignore the first function and the first half of funk2 as well. It all works just fine, the problem I have only has to do with passing the twodimensional array.

The result of this code is an error in

```
    funk2(N,T[][N]);
```

(expected expression before ']' token).

Adding an N there results in

```
expected 'float (*)[(sizetype)(N)]' but argument is of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 2):

The only time `[]` is valid syntax is when declaring an array either with an initializer or as a function parameter.

If you want to pass an array to a function, just pass it:

```
funk2(N,T);
```

You don't need to call out the dimensions of the array.  The compiler knows it's an array.

Comment: That worked :) Thanks! Could I have some more insight on that though?

Comment: @ImReallyBadAtCoding: The *expression* `T` has type `float [N][N]`, so the compiler knows that it's an array type.

Comment: It's important to realize than when you pass an "array" to a function, you're not really passing the array, you're passing a pointer to its first element.  So the argument `float T[][N]` is really `float (*T)[N]`, and the compiler silently changes it to that for you.